# How to compile multiple scss files using grunt-sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I am trying to compile multiple .scss files into a single CSS file. This actually works but only grabs the first file...

```
sass: {                                 // Task
   dist: {     
     files: {
       'css/test.css':'sass/*.scss'
     }

   }
}
```

We don't have ruby installed so grunt-contrib-sass is not an option. I do the same thing in Stylus like this...

```
stylus: {
  compile : {
    files : {
      'css/g.css' : 'stylus/*.styl'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it is exact but close, did you just use the import because that is not an option for me.

Comment: The other question doesn't mention anything about not having Ruby installed, as this one does. But if they are dupes, I'd prefer to see an answer here, and to close the other as a dupe of this, since this question is clearly worded.
Usually Sass requires Ruby. Is it normal to have Grunt remove that dependency?

Comment: There are 2 versions of SASS, Ruby SASS and libSASS grunt-contrib-sass runs using ruby while grunt-sass uses node-sass which uses libsass. libsass is supposed to be faster because it is C(++?) based instead of Ruby (built on C). So yeah there is a bit of a difference I think I need to look into dynamic expansion per another post.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about running `grunt-contrib-concat` first?

```
concat: {
       dist: {
         src: [
           'sass/*.scss',
         ],
         dest: 'sass/build.scss',
       }
     },

sass: {                                 // Task
   dist: {     
     files: {
       'css/test.css':'sass/build.scss'
     }

   }
}
```

and then task:

```
grunt.registerTask('sass', ['concat', 'sass']);
```

**edit**

How are you using `@import`? I'm not an expert on the specifics, but here is what I do...

*dir/*

```
main.scss
_nav.scss
_vars.scss
etc.
```

*main.scss*

```
@import "nav";
@import "vars";
etc.
```

Comment: I'm not sure why OP *can't* use `@import`, but to anyone seeing this...I'm pretty sure that is generally the preferred method.

Comment: I would tend to agree, I was just not as familiar with how the sass framework handled linking(?). I do find it funny that the default behavior for sass seems to be to throw an exception whereas stylus creates too much css.

Comment: I've actually never used stylus myself. I've updated my answer...maybe your `@import`s aren't right?

Comment: If you have *.scss files broken up by modules, then you don't want to have to include them all in your `main.scss`, you just want Grunt to find them all via `src/**/*.scss`

Comment: In the situation that you don't want to concat all your stylesheets into one file, you wouldn't want to use import.

EG. You are building a custom wordpress app and want to load one style sheet for the login page, one style sheet for the admin, and one stylesheet for the front end.

Comment: What about the source maps in this situation?

Answer (score 15):

I just want to touch on this, because I had the same issue, and this will actually work:

```
    sass: { // Task
       dist: {         
         files: [{
             // Set to true for recursive search
             expand: true,
             cwd: 'scss/',
             src: ['**/*.scss'],
             dest: 'css/',
             ext: '.css'
         }]
       }
    }
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: just what I was looking for - I just wanted to 'batch' process one folder of scss files into another folder of convert-to-CSS files without having to list all of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "grunt-sass-globbing". It will generate a SCSS file with all the imports you specified in your Gruntfile.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass-globbing/

With this option you can keep your source maps and you don't need to concatenate your SCSS files.

#### Step 1: Create import file

```
sass_globbing: {
    your_target: {
        options: {
            useSingleQuotes: false,
            signature: '// Hello, World!'
        },
        files: {
            'imports.scss': 'partials/**/*.scss',
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step 2: Compile your import file

```
sass: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true
    },
    develop: {
        files: {
            'main.css': 'imports.scss'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna use concat, you can specify all files in directory. Checkout this example:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#compile-files-in-a-directory

Comment: "We don't have ruby installed so grunt-contrib-sass is not an option" .

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple.

let's say you have this structure with 2 scss files:

```
   scss/
       core/file.scss
       templates/file2.scss
       main.scss
```

so what you need to do is: create a file called: **main.scss** in your root scss folder and import all your scss files:

**e.g.: main.scss will have:**

```
@import "core/file.scss"
@import "templates/file2.scss"
```

now use grunt-contrib-sass and just call the **main.scss** file:

done :)

```
//Sass ===============================
            var sass;
            config.sass = sass = {};

                //production
                    sass.dist = {
                        options: { style: "compressed"}
                        , files: {
                            "public/stylesheets/myapp.production.css" : "sass/main.scss"
                        }
                    };

                //development env.
                    sass.dev = {
                    options: { style: "expanded", lineNumber: true}
                    , files: {
                        "public/stylesheets/myapp.development.css" : "sass/main.scss"
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Yes but what if I have 100 other scss files instead of 2? Then I have to do 100 imports rt?

Comment: yeah :), I suggest to you divide the project, I like the way this guy did look: https://github.com/douglasdeodato/lovelycss/tree/master/scss