# Empty CSS File Output When Converting SASS to CSS Using GruntJS

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to convert my sass file to css using gruntjs.
This is my Gruntfile.js :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    const sass = require('node-sass');
    // require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    // Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        // pass in options to plugins
        // refenrece to files etc
        sass: {
            options: {
                implementation: sass
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    src: 'sass/*.scss',
                    dest: 'css/main.css'
                }]
            }
        }
    });


    // Load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');


    // Register tasks
    grunt.registerTask('convert-sass', 'sass');    
}
```

When I run `grunt convert-sass`. The task is finished successfully. But the main.css is always empty.

[image: grunt convert-sass]

Is there any other configuration that I missed ?

I have tried to add `sourcemap: true` and changed

`files: [{
      'css/main.css': 'sass/*.scss'
   }]`
 but it's still empty

These are my sass files (located in sass directory)

adimixins.scss :

```
@mixin vishovact ($link_color, $visit_color, $hover_color, $active_color) {
    a {
        color: $link_color;
        &:visited {
            color: $visit_color;
        }

        &:hover {
            color: $hover_color;
        }

        &:active {
            color: $active_color;
        }
    }
}
```

style.scss:

```
@import 'adimixins';

$base-color: #7FFFD4;
$second-color: #FF00FF;
$mybackground: #008B8B;

// Buat satu biji kelas
.adi-class {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: $mybackground;
    @include vishovact('blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green');
    p {
        color: $second-color;
    }
}
```

*any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you share your SASS file code as well please? I just tried your code with a minimal `.scss` file and it worked. Also, please share your folder structure. Thanks.

Comment: @GurtejSingh I have added my sass files. Thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118598/how-to-compile-multiple-scss-files-using-grunt-sass you need to run grunt-contrib-concat first to have one file and then convert .

Comment: @UserEsp, Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after several trials. I realized that no need to convert the mixins.scss. Because it's already converted automatically. So I change the `src: 'sass/*.scss'` to `src: 'sass/styles.scss',` and it finally works. Here's the output of converted css file:

```
.adi-class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #008B8B; }
  .adi-class a {
    color: "blue"; }
    .adi-class a:visited {
      color: "red"; }
    .adi-class a:hover {
      color: "yellow"; }
    .adi-class a:active {
      color: "green"; }
  .adi-class p {
    color: #FF00FF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check ruby with `ruby -v` (install [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/) )
2. Install Sass with `sudo gem install sass` (install [sass](https://sass-lang.com/install) )

   setting for Grunt Tasks & run `grunt convert-sass`

   ```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {

     grunt.initConfig({
     pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

     sass: {
         dist: {
             options: {
               sourcemap: 'none'
             },
             files: [{
                 expand: true,
                 cwd: 'sass',
                 src: ['**/*.scss'],
                 dest: 'css',
                 ext: '.css'
             }]
            }
          }

       });

      // Load Grunt plugins
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

      // Register Grunt tasks
      grunt.registerTask('convert-sass', 'sass');
   };
   ```

Comment: Hy Shiv Kumar. Thank you for you answer.
I'm not using ruby or grunt-contrib-sass in this project. So it's different with your case. Thank you :-)

Comment: can you check if cmd line working and you are getting css out of SCSS. run `node-sass --output-style compressed -o main/css sass/style.scss`